# compare existing month and year only in database after chosing date in java date picker

Tags: java, oracle, javafx

After chosing the date in date picker in java,i've got this format `dd/mm/yyyy`.But before inserting it in Oracle database i want first to compare only if month and year exist,not the day.If the month and year is already recorded i don't insert, if not,i insert it and reset the only the day to the first day of the month,but keep the month and year as they are.My program is only concerned by date and month,that why i want to know how to compare only the two before inserting.I've tried to do the following code:

```
Resultset res = st.executeQuery("select count(*) as rowCont from doc_arriv where month_arv=to_char(chosen_date,'mm/YYYY');
res.next();
```

But it isn't comparing

Comment: What *exactly* is the data type for the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
calendar=java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(chosen_date);

//we must add 1 here beacause Calendar intialise months by zero
int month= calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;

//we get the year
int year= calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String req = "SELECT count(*) from doc_arriv where
EXTRACT(month FROM month_arv) = " +  month + 
"and   EXTRACT(year FROM month_arv)= " = year ;

Resultset res=st.executeQuery(req);
res.next();

//continue your code here you must calculate the result of the request if more than 1 you insert else you dont insert and for change the day to the first day of month you must execute the code 

 calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
chosen_date= calendar.getTime();

//good luck
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all better use a `PreparedStatement`. Then simply compare the dates of the with the first day of the month and the first day of the next month (assuming the type of the `month_arv` column is `DATE`):

```
LocalDate date = ...
LocalDate startOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate startOfNextMonth = startOfMonth.plusMonths(1);

// save for later use (insertion)
Date sqlStartOfMonth = Date.valueOf(startOfMonth);

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM doc_arriv WHERE month_arv >= ? AND month_arv < ?");
statement.setDate(1, sqlStartOfMonth);
statement.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(startOfNextMonth));

ResultSet res = startment.executeQuery();
```